# How to fix NullPointerException on Autowired JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I am re-writing my question to hopefully make more sense and get some help.

I have a `Controller`, 2 `ClassRepository`, and 2 `Service` classes (one of which is not annotated with @Service as I get an error when I annotate it, so instead I just use it as a class)

The class not annotated with @Service I simply pass the `rateRepository` object from the annotated Service to the unannotated service.

If I execute the following code in my annotated service

```
String zone = rateRepository.getPurolatorZone(request.getShipToZip().substring(0,3));
```

it works great.

however in my unannotated class where i instantiate the class

```
InternationalRateService internationalRateService = new InternationalRateService(this.rateRepository);
```

**UPDATE:** 
I annotated my `InternationalRateService` class with `@Service` and decided to autowire the repository itself, and I still get a null pointer exception on the getPurolatorZone method.. I dont understand why it works in one service but not the other when they are set up the same.

**Second Update:**
as it turns out, im an idiot because i didn't even think to check that it was possible that the string i pass to the repository was what was actually throwing the error. Turns out I never set the local shiptozip variable so. yea im an idiot .

Answer (score 0):

Spring will inject dependencies only in spring managed beans. If you create an object with `new` then it's not spring managed bean.

In your case, object of  `InternationalRateService` is not managed, as you created by `new` operator.

So, inject `InternationalRateService` in your controller, so that all dependencies are injected